# Can be smoothing image in a loaded SWF?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, smoothing

I'm trying to load an SWF into another in AS3/Haxe. The loaded SWF contains some images - but only on some `Shape.graphics` elements. (Like `graphics.beginBitmapFill();` ...)
This images are not smoothed, and jaggy.
Can this images be smoothed anyhow during runtime?
Any hack interested! :)

Thanks in advance!
Tom

**Update:** Sorry, but I forget to mention, that I'm loading more AS2-SWFs (AVM1) into one AS3-SWF (AVM2) with [AVM2Loader](http://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/source/browse/trunk/FlexPaper/src/com/devaldi/streaming/AVM2Loader.as), which hack the loaded bytes, and convert the AVM1 SWFs into AVM2 - it works very well. :)

So, in these SWFs I need to find the images/bitmaps, but only found the `Shapes`, which `graphics` elements has the 'images'. If I clear this `graphics`, then all images are gone, so I think, the images are in some `graphics.beginBitmapFill(...);`, without smoothing. I want to reach them, and switch smoothing on at runtime, if possible.
(Sorry, if the first time I was not enough clear.)

Edit (Jan 23 '14): I found solution for it. It is not fast, and required Flash Player 11.6. Every `MovieClip` graphics properties has a new `readGraphicsData` function, which give all the graphics commands (`Vector IGraphicsData`) to draw the whole MC. And iterate in these commands, if I change every `bitmapFill` command `smooth` parameter to true, and redraw the MC, it will be smoothed, and nice.
That's it. Not fast, but working.

Comment: Try `stage.quality=StageQuality.HIGH` and see if anything changed.

Comment: The quality is on `BEST`, but I tried `HIGH_8X8`, and `HIGH_16X16`, but nothing. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for it. It is not fast, and required Flash Player 11.6. Every `MovieClip` graphics properties has a new `readGraphicsData` function, which give all the graphics commands (`Vector IGraphicsData`) to draw the whole MC. And iterate in these commands, if I change every `bitmapFill` command `smooth` parameter to true, and redraw the MC, it will be smoothed, and nice.
That's it. Not fast, but working.

Comment: If I remember correctly: Using **readGraphichData(recursive:Boolean = true)** on a **Graphics object**, you will get a **Vector.<IGraphicsData>**. If you iterate on it and find every **GraphicsBitmapFill**. And if the smooth parameter is false, then set it to true, and set a variable to true too, so you will know that need to redraw the shape itself.
And if you changed something then you "just" need to use **drawGraphicsData(graphicsData:Vector.<IGraphicsData>)** with the modified graphics data and you are done.

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onLoad(event):Void
{
   pic.forceSmoothing  = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but **forceSmoothing** is not supported in **AS3**, that is the probleme. (In AS2 it is working.)

Answer (score 0):

[Smoothing is a property of bitmaps](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#smoothing) that's off by default.

```
var image = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
image.smoothing = true;
```

Typically, your bitmapData will be in the loader.content.bitmapData when loading externally, but it's up to you were you've stored it.

---

**Update:**

If you want to smooth all images in a loaded SWF without any knowledge of the structure of the SWF, then you'll have to recursively dig through the hiarchy of that SWF, and depending on whether or not the object is a Bitmap, turn on smoothing.

```
function recursivelySmooth(obj):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; obj.getChildAt(i); i++) {
        var item:* = obj.getChildAt(i);
        if (item is Bitmap) {
            item.smoothing = true;
        } else if (item.hasOwnProperty("numChildren") == true) {
            recursivelySmooth(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This was written freehand, so you may have to doublecheck everything is correct, but that's the basic idea.  Just call recursivelySmooth() on your swf, and it'll dig through all objects that can have child elements and smooth them.

Comment: But I'm loading SWF, not BitmapData. And if I locate the shape, which contain the images, and I clear this shape's graphics element, the image is gone.
I want to locate the images through the loaded SWF, but how? Any low level 'hack' is interesting, just be runtime!

Comment: **Update:** Thanks, this is much better, and I figured out, too. But it is not working on these SWFs. :-/